# what is the purpose of using @media and @page in media='print' css files

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm researching existing html5 application.

Its html page contains style for print

```
  <link href="receipt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

receipt.css file contains also @media and @page directives

```
.myreceipt {
    @page {
        visibility: hidden;
        margin: 0 15px;
    }

    @page {
        height: auto;
    }
}

    .myreceipt body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

@media screen {

    .myreceipt #receipt-header img {
        width: 300px;
    }
}

.myreceipt #receipt {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

@media print {
    .myreceipt #receipt {
        color: #000;
    }
}
```

Why css file contains media directives ? If html file contains `media='print'` is it used only for printing ?
Can `@media screen` elements deleted fully from css file and `@media print` directives removed safely ?
Or is there some reason for them, this css is created by proffessionals ?

Why `visibility: hidden` is specified in @page ?
According to doc, `visibility: hidden` is ignored for `@page`, can it safely removed ?
Can @page also removed since html file contains media=print and in this case @page is always used ?

Comment: That is indeed strange. Maybe the author is anticipating that the stylesheet might be included for screen media elsewhere somehow, and trying to account for it in case it happens.

Comment: This explains other issues but why `@page { visibility: hidden` is used. Can it safely removed, I tested and receipt appears so it looks like Chrome ignores it

Comment: According to MDN, `The @page CSS at-rule is used to modify some CSS properties when printing a document. You can't change all CSS properties with @page. You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored.`. Also media query is to decide the css rules against a particular screen size.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: @Vinit Kumar According to http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-page/#at-page-rule visibility can used in @ page sub-elements but this code uses it for @ page root element. What this means ?

Comment: It means it changes the margin of `.myreciept` class while using print.

Comment: @Vinit Kumar: It's very obvious from this example that media queries aren't just used for screen size.

Comment: @Vinit Kumar `visibility: hidden` is used to make element invisible. It does not change margin. Maybe it is used to hide builtit headers and footers added by browser? However browser added page header and footer still appear is browser. Is `@page` syntax legal, it does not follow to css standard ?

Comment: @BoltClock I know they are used for many other use cases as well. I just gave an example about a part in code. Rest was pretty obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Why css file contains media directives ?
- Or is there some reason for them, this css is created by proffessionals ?

Because it could be used for different media (e.g. screen, print, etc)

- If html file contains media='print' is it used only for printing ?

Yes.

- Can @media screen elements deleted fully from css file and @media print directives removed safely ?

Only if the file is linked from link elements using media="print".

- Why visibility: hidden is specified in @page ? According to doc, visibility: hidden is ignored for @page, can it safely removed ?

That's for CSS 2.1. It does/will matter for CSS 3 (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-page/#content-empty). However, as of now, in Firefox 25, both visibility and height are invalid, hence ignored.

- Can @page also removed since html file contains media=print and in this case @page is always used ?

Yes, but also for a different (better) reason: at-rules (@page, @media) must be defined top level. As it is in your style sheet, with @page inside .myreceipt, they are simply ignored so you might as well delete them.

If they weren't ignored (ie. outside of .myreceipt) then you should be aware that @page refers to the actual print area on a page, not to the .myreceipt (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page). So if you want to remove them, you would have to apply some equivalent formatting to the body element.

I would like to close by pointing out that in this case "created by professionals" probably refers more to someone being paid, than someone being an expert in this stuff.

Andrei